# Adding weighted edges to my linked list graph in c

Tags: c, graph, linked-list

So I'm trying to build a graph data structure with towns as the nodes and the edges as the distance between them. I want to create an adjacency list for each node/location and add a weighted edges. So far I've created a linked list program which asks the user how many nodes they want. The user can then name each node when they've been created and it prints out a linked list with the nodes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char city[20];
    int weight;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node *createLinkedList(int n);
void displayList(node *head);

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    node *HEAD = NULL;
    printf("\nHow many nodes:\t");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    HEAD = createLinkedList(n);
    displayList(HEAD);

    return 0;
}

node *createLinkedList(int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    node *head = NULL;
    node *temp = NULL;
    node *p = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // create an individual node

        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("\nEnter the name of the city: ", i+1);
        scanf("\t%s",(temp->city));
        temp->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL) //if list is currently empty, then make temp as first node
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            p = head;
            while(p->next != NULL)
                p = p->next;
            p->next = temp;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

void displayList(node *head)
{
    node *p = head;

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("\t%s->",p->city);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

Now, I want the user to specify the weights of each edge and for it to be printed. I've tried to do this myself but to no avail. I've specified a weight int in the structure at the top. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `scanf` as the you used for `city`. Using the type format `%d` for `int`.

```
printf("\nEnter the name of the city %d: ", i+1);
scanf("\t%19s",(temp->city));
printf("\nEnter the the weight of the city %d: ", i+1);
scanf("\t%d",&(temp->weight));
```

For printing the weight:

```
printf("weight = %d\n",p->weight);
```

Is that you want ?

UPDATE:

If you want to request the sub-sequence of linked-list, you can add two argument `start`, `end` into the create and display function.

```
node *createLinkedList(int n, int start, int end);
void displayList(node *head, int start, int end);
```

For create function:

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ....
        if (start <= i && i <= end) {
            printf("\nEnter the the weight of the city %d: ", i+1);
            scanf("\t%d",&(temp->weight));
        }
        ...
    }
```

For display function, you can use the `counter` for the order of the node in list:

```
   int counter = 0;

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        ...
        if (start <= counter && counter <= end) {
            printf("\n weight =  %d \n", p->weight);
        }
        ...
        counter++;
        p = p->next;
    }
```

Then, when you call function, for example, you want to print from 2nd node to 4th node.

```
displayList(HEAD, 1, 3);
```

If you dont want to add the `start` and `end` values, or you want to work many time with sub-sequence, you can add one parameter `int index` into the struc for tracking the order of each node.

```
typedef struct node
{
    char city[20];
    int weight;
    int index
    struct node *next;
}node;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that very helpful. I forgot to mention that I don't want it to ask the weight to the first node as this is where i'll be starting from. I just want to request the weight of each subsequent node if you know how to change it to do that. Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to scanf and print the weight values of node 3, 4, 5, for example ?

Comment: Yes, thats what im after.